# What do +++ and --- mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jslint

My work is based on JSLint. I saw that JSLint is able to handle `+++` and `---` operator. I searched these operator on Internet but found nothing.

What do these two operators mean in JavaScript?

Comment: maybe you have seen something like `c= a + ++b;` ?

Answer (score 10):

There is no such operator. `+++` is parsed as `++ +`. Writing code with this in it is usually a bad idea.

Comment: oh thanks I forgot that

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't supports +++,--- instead it supports increment/decrement operators.